# Rails/Spree -bash: spree: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have worked with rails before and i thought that i would try out spree to learn more about engines. Following the getting started tutorial on sprees [documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html) it seemed very strait forward. I installed the gem `gem install spree_cmd` and then added `gem 'spree'` to the gemfile and ran bundler which ran fine. It installed several spree gems. But on the instruction to run `spree install --auto-accept` it returns

```
$ spree install --auto-accept
-bash: spree: command not found
```

I am running on mac OS X 10.8.4. ruby 1.9.3p327 rails 2.3.13 and rbenv and my ruby manager

any thing i am missing?

Comment: Did you run `rails g spree:site`?

Comment: yeah the same thing comes up

Comment: Try using `bundle exec spree install --auto-accept`.

Comment: that seemed to do something. its says that i need the spree_cmd gem in the gemfile as well. and that spree needs to be 2.0.3 and that jruby needs to be 2.2.1, with that set up it works!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to Add gem 'spree' to the Gemfile and after that
$ bundle install
and then $ spree install --auto-accept

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too! And I tried to search for a solution. Well, spree require an exact version of ruby and rails. So I think you need to install a correct ruby version. Try run :

```
$rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

This makes the spree command works for me